# Convert Java/C style formula to excel formula

Tags: worksheet-function, vba

Related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/427638/excel-exporting-formula-to-other-languages) question, but I want to do it in the other direction

I am trying to convert these nested Java/C style formulas into excel. eg:

```
(Func("A") && Func("B"))||(~Func("C") && Func("D"))
```

becomes

```
=OR(AND(Func("A"),Func("B")),AND(NOT(Func("C")),Func("D")))
```

I can translate the `Func()` into VBA functions, but as I have over 1500 formulas listed, I would prefer to automate the conversion

Any solution that uses VBA, Formulas, or external libraries that are free would be welcome

Comment: The best I could suggest is to parse your formulas and do find&replace. I think you'd have better luck at stackoverflow. You can request a migration.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type).

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in Excel functions to substitute desired strings instead of other determined strings, such as:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D2,"AND"," == ")
```

You can also read the formula into a string in VBA, perform the same operation, and place the formula back in excel. The

```
strFormula = Cells(2, 4).Formula
strFormula = Replace(strFormula, "AND", " == ")
Cells(2, 4).Formula = strFormula
```

I hope this helps.